# is_null behaviour php laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, isnull

I was in the process of building a small API system using laravel.
This is a small piece of code from it which searches for user, and if it exists, sends a json response back. When I ran this code such that it should return no user(usercontent is {}), the is_null still returns false. I thought it should return true in this case. 
I had planned to use it in my code to check if certain users exist, but now it seems to be failing everytime.

have i misunderstood something? Can someone explain what I missed? Thanks.

Response code:

```
if($user)
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => 'true',
        'message' => 'User exists.',
        'user' => is_null($user),
        'usertype' => gettype($user),
        'usercontent' => $user
    ), 400);
}
```

Response json:

```
{
    "error":"true",
    "message":"User exists.",
    "user":false,
    "usertype":"object",
    "usercontent":{}
}
```

EDIT:

i did a

```
var_dump($user);
var_dump(empty($user));
```

which seem to return

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#201 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } } 
bool(false)
```

EDIT 2:

```
$user = User::where('mobile_number', '=', Request::get('mobile_number'))
                    ->orwhere('email_id', '=', Request::get('email_id'))
                    ->take(1)
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Why don't you `var_dump($user)` and see what it has to say. I'm not clear under what cases `json` will come up with `{}`, it may not be just for `null` values.

Comment: Did you try using `empty($user)` instead of `is_null($user)` ? Also, the output of `gettype($user)` points out that the `$user` variable is an object, so it is not `null`.

Comment: Assuming this `json` function works like PHP's builtin `json_encode`, it looks like an object of a class without any public members is also encoded to `{}`.

Comment: Another thing is if the $user object is null, `if($user)` would return false and the block would not be executed. Could you add some code for getting the `$user` variable?

Comment: i just made an edit based on what you guys asked. 
it is a non empty object afterall. Would I have to remove the protected from my models to get a proper return?

Comment: @AnuragRamdasan, you are getting an `Eloquent\Collection` but I think the object type should be `Eloquent\Model` if a user exists, or it should be null in the case where there is not a user.

Comment: yes it struck me as soon as i posted it. Weird that I am getting a collection. any idea how that could have happened? my user class extends Eloquent.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the way you assign `$user`. If you could provide some code, I think we could help.

Comment: Edited. Is using get() returning a collection? despite it being take(1)? Will only first() suffice here? Also if you have an answer, please do post it as answer, so I can accept it and close the thread.

Comment: Yeah, try `first()` instead of `take(1)->get()`

Comment: that does work. So basically, even take(1) returns a collection?

Comment: Yes, `take()` makes the returned object a collection, so that you can iterate through them. I am wrapping it up in an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edited question, if you use `take()` the returned object would be a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, instead of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, even if the returned collection has one model object, or none (in that case, an empty collection will be returned).

Instead, you can use `find()` and get a model object using the primary key, or add `first()` to your query to get the first result from the query as a model object. These two methods will return `null` if the query does not match an entry.

For example:

`$user = User::find(1);`

Output:

```
{
  "error":"true",
  "message":"User exists.",
  "user":false,
  "usertype":"object",
  "usercontent":{
    "timestamps":true,
    "autoHashPasswordAttributes":true,
    "validationErrors":{},
    "throwOnValidation":false,
    "autoHydrateEntityFromInput":false,
    "forceEntityHydrationFromInput":false,
    "autoPurgeRedundantAttributes":false,
    "incrementing":true,
    "exists":true
  }
}
```

`$user = User::find(483);`

Output: empty

For your specific query, you can modify it as the following code to make it work:

```
$user = User::where('mobile_number', '=', Request::get('mobile_number'))
                    ->orwhere('email_id', '=', Request::get('email_id'))
                    ->first()
```